# how do you 'connect' this source code with my tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, encryption

hi am new to python and i have created a very simple encryption code and a simple gui with tkinter
but i cant seem to 'connect' them together i tried so hard but i need help right now

```
def machine():
    global newMessage
    keys = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz !"
    values = keys[-1] + keys[0:-1]


    encryptDict = dict(zip(keys, values))
    decryptdict = dict(zip(values, keys))

    message = input("Enter your message so i can encrypt or decrypt it :) ")
    mode = input("encrypt(E) OR decrypt(D) ")
    if mode.upper() == "E":
        newMessage = ''.join([encryptDict[letter] for letter in message.lower()])
    elif mode.upper() == "D":
        newMessage = ''.join([decryptdict[letter] for letter in message.lower()])
    else:
        print("use either E or D ")

    return newMessage

print(machine())
```

that is the encryption method

```
import tkinter as tk

HIGHT = 240
WIDTH = 720

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your message so i can encrypt or decrypt it :)")
label.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.125)

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.125)

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.125)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Incrypt")
button.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.125, relheight=0.125)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Decrypt")
button.place(relx=0.18, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.125, relheight=0.125)

root.mainloop()
```

and that is the gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the 'command' parameter in the `Button` widget to set it to an event handler which in your case is `machine`. Since you are encrypting and decrypting under the same function send a signal when calling this function as shown below using `lambda` function. Also, replace  `message = input("Enter your message so i can encrypt or decrypt it :) ")` with `message=entry.get()`. You have assigned `entry=Entry()` twice I assume that's a mistake so remove it. Finally instead of `return` use the existing label widget to display output
using `config` or you can also create a new label and use that for displaying the output.

Here is the complete code, which you may further improvise:

```
import tkinter as tk

HIGHT = 240
WIDTH = 720

def machine(mode):
    global newMessage
    keys = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz !"
    values = keys[-1] + keys[0:-1]

    encryptDict = dict(zip(keys, values))
    decryptdict = dict(zip(values, keys))

    message = entry.get()

    if mode == 0:
        newMessage = ''.join([encryptDict[letter] for letter in message.lower()])

    elif mode == 1:
        newMessage = ''.join([decryptdict[letter] for letter in message.lower()])
    
    label.config(text='Message: '+ newMessage)

   
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your message so i can encrypt or decrypt it :)")
label.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.125)

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.125)


button = tk.Button(root, text="Encrypt", command=lambda :machine(0))
button.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.125, relheight=0.125)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Decrypt", command=lambda :machine(1))
button2.place(relx=0.18, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.125, relheight=0.125)

root.mainloop()
```

**Update**:

To insert the text into the `Entry` widget use `Entry.insert(index, string)`. Also, don't forget to clear the existing text in the `Entry` by using `Entry.delete(0, END)`, the 'END' specifier will make sure that it deletes all the text starting from 0th index.

```
import tkinter as tk

HIGHT = 240
WIDTH = 720

def machine(mode):
    global newMessage
    keys = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz !"
    values = keys[-1] + keys[0:-1]

    encryptDict = dict(zip(keys, values))
    decryptdict = dict(zip(values, keys))

    message = entry.get()

    if mode == 0:
        newMessage = ''.join([encryptDict[letter] for letter in message.lower()])

    elif mode == 1:
        newMessage = ''.join([decryptdict[letter] for letter in message.lower()])

    entry2.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry2.insert(0,'Message: '+ newMessage)

   
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your message so i can encrypt or decrypt it :)")
label.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.125)

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.125)

entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.125)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Encrypt", command=lambda :machine(0))
button.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.125, relheight=0.125)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Decrypt", command=lambda :machine(1))
button2.place(relx=0.18, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.125, relheight=0.125)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this helped me so much thank you
but i need the answer to be copied and i cant copy label text
the second entry was for the answer so how do i make the answer to go to the second entry

Comment: @HamzaDualfoqar I have added an update if you found this useful hit the tick mark beside the answer. If you have any further queries, comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `message = entry.config()`.
`config()` takes what you have typed into the `entry` label and assigns it into the `message` variable.

Also you should assign to a button your functions,

`button_incrypt = tk.Button(root, text="Incrypt", command=incrypt)`
`button_decrypt = tk.Button(root, text="Decrypt", command=decrypt)`

In general i suggest, make two different functions, one each for every button,
as well two entries, by which those functions will absorb the encrypted/decrypted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `mode` and `message` to `machine()` function instead of using `input()` to get them:

```py
ENCRYPT = "E"
DECRYPT = "D"

def machine(mode, message):
    keys = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz !"
    values = keys[-1] + keys[:-1]

    mydict = dict(zip(keys, values)) if mode == ENCRYPT else dict(zip(values, keys))
    return "".join(mydict[letter] for letter in message.lower())
```

Then you can use `command` option to call `machine()` with required arguments:

```py
entry_message = tk.Entry(root)
entry_message.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.125)

result = tk.StringVar()  # use it for easier update of the result entry box
entry_result = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=result)
entry_result.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.125)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Encrypt", command=lambda: result.set(machine(ENCRYPT, entry_message.get())))
button.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.125, relheight=0.125)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Decrypt", command=lambda: result.set(machine(DECRYPT, entry_message.get())))
button.place(relx=0.18, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.125, relheight=0.125)
```